# Separate App initialize based on environment like (prod, dev, test, stag) in Firebase-Admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am considering using **Firebase-Admin** in node.js, however I couldn't find any reliable solution to the following problem:

I want to initialize app based on current environment like pro, dev, stag, testing

I have 4 application under 1 project of Firebase Console.

I am initializing app like this

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccountKey),
  databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXX.firebaseio.com"
})
```

Here serviceAccountKey is same for all 4 application. How can  separate it?

Answer (score 0):

Use application default credentials. Have the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable set to the environment-specific service account file. Other settings (like databaseURL), can be loaded via the `FIREBASE_CONFIG` environment variable, if needed.